# How to display a selected location along with all other locations using gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails, rails-3.1

I am trying to figure out why when I have a map displaying a controller's json string for map locations, when I click the infobox and go to a specific id page, I cannot zoom to the specific id location, and KEEP the rest of the locations on map. For instance:

The map displaying all of the points from the places_controller:

```
def index
 @json = Places.all.to_gmaps4rails
end
```

The individual id page displaying itself:

```
def show
 @json = Places.find(params[:id]).to_gmaps4rails
end
```

I want the .find(params[:id]).to_gmaps4rails to include .all of the places, but center on the :id location.

ps- the index map is geoLocated and centers on user, whereas the show location centers on just the 1 marker entry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
def show
  @json   = Places.all.to_gmaps4rails
  @center = Places.find(params[:id])
end
```

And in view:

```
<%= gmaps( :map_options => { :center_latitude => @center.latitude, :center_longitude => @center.longitude, :zoom => 6 },
           :markers     => { :data => @json } 
         ) %>
```

Comment: This worked, the only thing I did have to change was :auto_adjust => true, TO :auto_adjust => false.